# Is it possible to use custom written extension libraries(not published to mvn repo) with maven jmeter plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I developed custom extension Jar to generate JWT tokens and currently invoking that code within a JSR223 PreProcessor to JWT token.All works well on standalone Jmeter3,2 version adding Jar to lib/ext folder.
Now want to run the script via mvn JMeter plugin https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin .
I see its possible to retrieve third-party Jars available on mvn repos. But wondering whether Is their way to do the same with locally build Jars?

Answer (score 2):

1. [Install your .jar into your local Maven repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) using command like:

   ```
   mvn jar:jar install:install -Dfile=com.blazemeter.test-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.blazemeter -DartifactId=com.blazemeter.test -Dversion=1.0
   ```
2. [Configure JMeter Maven plugin to use this .jar as an additional library](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath) like:

   ```
   <testPlanLibraries>
       <artifact>com.blazemeter:com.blazemeter.test:1.0</artifact>
   </testPlanLibraries>
   ```
3. That's it, [Eclipse Aether](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.aether) will find the .jar in your local repo. Just remember to perform step 1 for all JMeter slaves or on any other machine where you will be running your test. You can also consider [publishing your .jar to Maven Central repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html) so other community members could use it as well (if it is not very specific to your application)

You can also see [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more information on running a JMeter test using command-line, build systems, Java code, etc.